# How to run multiple agg functions and return them as rows in a pandas data frame?

Tags: pandas

Given a data frame that looks like this:

```
  id  x  y
   1  6  4
   2  5  5
   1  4  6
   2  3  7
   1  2  8
   2  1  9
```

How do I run multiple aggregate functions (e.g. `min` and `max`) over a column but return them as as rows of a data frame?  The expected output should be:

```
   minmax
   1
   6
```

In R's dplyr, I could do something like this but I don't know how to make it work in pandas.

```
summarize(df, tibble(minmax = c(min(x), max(x))))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run multiple function with `agg`

```
df[['x','y']].agg(['max','min'])
Out[211]: 
     x  y
max  6  9
min  1  4
```